# Json data type is not working on mariadb

Tags: sql, json, mariadb

Please help me to make this sql working.

```
create table testjson(data json);
```

This query does not work because of the json type.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'json)' at line 1
```

I am using mariadb10. This is the output when I connect with mysql command.

```
$ mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.5.5-10.0.24-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no JSON datatype, at least not in the rather old Version 5.5.